How to specify a generic over TypedDict?
I want to have a class, that has the following members:

function f, that takes argument of type In, and kwargs specified by Parameters
function make_parameters that returns Parameters, that can be directly fed into f

The code I have now is:
In = TypeVar("In", contravariant=True)
Out = TypeVar("Out", covariant=True)
Parameters = TypeVar("Parameters", bound=TypedDict)


class Function(Generic[In, Out, Parameters]):

    class FProtocol(Protocol):
        def __call__(self, x: In, **parameters: Unpack[Parameters]) -> Out: ...

    def __init__(
        self,
        f: FProtocol,
        make_parameters: Callable[[], Parameters],
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._f = f
        self._make_parameters = make_parameters

    def __call__(self, x: In) -> Tuple[Out, Parameters]:
        parameters = self._make_parameters()

        return self._f(x, **parameters), parameters

However, type hints don't work:

I can't bind Parameters by TypedDict
Unpack expects a TypedDict

I could just make parameters a positional argument, but I would prefer it being more natural, with parameters being named arguments.
I would want to be able to use my class in the following way:
def example_f(x: float, a: float, b: float) -> float:
    return a * x + b

class ExampleParameters(TypedDict):
    a: float
    b: float


f = Function[float, float, ExampleParameters](example_f, lambda: {"a": 1.0, "b": 2.0})


Two issues:

Parameters = TypeVar("Parameters", bound=TypedDict)
This doesn't work, because, despite the Python syntax used to build a typing.TypedDict type, typing.TypedDict itself is not a type. Simple demo:
from typing import TypedDict

var: TypedDict  # Type-checker error

The way to specify a base TypedDict type is by defining an empty typed dictionary:
class BaseTypedDict(TypedDict):
    pass

...

Parameters = TypeVar("Parameters", bound=BaseTypedDict)

This will work for any typed dictionary regardless of "inheritance" from BaseTypedDict, because typed dictionaries are structural types, not nominal types.

def __call__(self, x: In, **parameters: Unpack[Parameters]) -> Out: ...
This is not available in Python (yet). See Feature Request: Allow unpacking of type variable bound to typed dict - typing


